# Understanding how WordPress hooks are called

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Here is how my current action hook example: it changes the meta description of the HTML page.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_a_description' );

  function add_a_description () {
    echo '<meta name="description" content=" This is new content" />' . "
";

  } // End example
```

Now to me (I have some basic PHP knowledge, nothing more), it looks like the function is being called before it's been made. My intuition tells me that it should look like:

```
      function add_a_description () {
        echo '<meta name="description" content=" This is new content" />' . "
    ";}

  add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_a_description' );  // End example
```

I understand this isn't the case, but I don't know why. Could someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not matter where you write the action hook both will work:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_a_description' );

function add_a_description () {
    echo '<meta name="description" content=" This is new content" />' . "";
}
```

and

```
function add_a_description () {
    echo '<meta name="description" content=" This is new content" />' . "";
} 

add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_a_description' );  // End example
```

These both will work. It does not matter where you declare the function, the only thing is that the function should be included in the script.

This is because the `whole file is first parsed and then executed`.

From [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php)

**Functions need not be defined before they are referenced, except when a function is conditionally defined.**

Regarding the `wp_head` action hook. The `wp_head` function resides inside `wp-includes/general-template.php`

If you look at that function it will call `do_action('wp_head');`

What this does is that, it will check for all actions and filters defined with **wp_head** hook which is stored in the global variable **$wp_actions**

If there is a hook in for wp_head it will call the hooked function using **call_user_func_array**

Hope this helps you :-)

Comment: Do many other languages allow the functions to be defined either way?

Comment: I think in c, c++ you cant do that. You need to declare the function before using it or do a forward declaration. I am not sure about other languages. I think most others support

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing all of the inner workings, you can think of `add_action()` as simple function which passes the name of a function to be called at a certain point. In your code, `add_action()` lets the system know to call the function `add_a_description()` when it reaches the `wp_head` point.

Here's a VERY basic example of how the code works:

```
// Start of example system
$actions = array();

function add_action($point, $name) {
  global $actions;
  $actions[$point][] = $name;
}

function run($point) {
  global $actions;
  foreach ($actions[$point] as $name)
    $name();
}
// End of example system

// Start of example plugin / theme function
add_action('wp_head', 'alert');
function alert() {
  echo 'hello';
}
// End of example plugin / theme function

// At point wp_head
run('wp_head');
```